# Journey Builder engagement split treats click on Email update profile link as success

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

If a subscriber clicks on Update Profile link in an email,the journey builder counts/treats it as a click in an engagement split.Any suggestion/way to make JB, treat clicks made on Update Profile link, as a negative click. It should ideally consider only the clicks made on other links in the email and not those on Update Profile link.

Answer (score 2):

One caveat for the 'new' engagement split feature - the links need to be distinct for them to be eligible for individual selection.

Let's say you had an email that had 4 different images of shirts, and you wanted to measure and react to which shirt gets the most clicks and then customize they next email in the journey to feature similar shirts, but you wanted all 4 of those images to link to the same landing page (let's say a shop with all 4 shirts in it) with the same base URL, such as https://mycoolsite.com/shirts - and have them individually show up as selections for your engagement split, you can't, because they are treated as the same link when measuring the click.

You would need to have 4 separate base URLs to create engagement splits from those images independently.

Image 1 > https://mycoolsite.com/shirts1

Image 2 > ../shirts2

...etc.

Please correct me if I am wrong, but that is what my experience has been thus far.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an easy way around this one. The only solution I can think of is quite convoluted, but maybe you can improve it. This is what I have:

- Make a note of the linkname or URL for the profile / subscription center link within the emails used in your Journey
- Query the SFMC data views, in particular the Click data view. Remember you only want to pull in users that have met two conditions: exist in your Journey Source Data Extension, and have clicked on a link from that email ID that doesn't equal the profile or subscription center
- Mark a boolean field in a Data Extension with true/false - true for all users you pulled back in the previous query, false for all users who didn't meet those requirements
- Add a decision split instead of engagement split in your Journey. This decision split will look at the true/false field we created in the previous step to make sure only users who have been identified as clicking on a link outside of the profile / subscription center are added.

I'm not sure how feasible that solution is, but maybe it will get your brain thinking in new directions.

Additional information on the Click data view: https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_click/

Good luck!

---

UPDATE:

Great update in the July '16 release:

New Features

Link-Level Engagement Splits

This release adds the ability to configure engagement splits based on one or more specific links in an email. In addition to monitoring engagement of all links in an email, this feature gives you more flexibility to target subscribers based on specific interactions within an email.

[image]

Haven't tested yet but seems much better!

Comment: Note on this for those getting to this post...this does not apply to dynamic links.